# not able to execute this programme. Error : Invalid syntax random.py

Tags: python, random

```
import random

print "\n wlecome to fortune game"


your_fortune = random.randrange(1,8)

if your_fortune == 1:
    print "your are lucky"
else:
    print "you are not lucky"
```

raw_input("press enter to exit")

Comment: Your code looks fine, post the exact traceback message.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I think the edition of Ashwini already did the job. When I look at you original code, it says this:

```
import random
print "\n wlecome to fortune game"
your_fortune = random.randrange(1,8)
if your_fortune == 1: print "your are lucky" else: print "you are not lucky"
raw_input("press enter to exit")
```

At the fourth line, I see an if and else statement on the same line. Thats an invallid syntax. Use this:

```
import random

print "\nWelcome to fortune game"
your_fortune = random.randrange(1,8)
if your_fortune == 1: print "your are lucky"
else: print "you are not lucky"

raw_input("press enter to exit")
```

Or this:

```
import random

print "\nWelcome to fortune game"
your_fortune = random.randrange(1,8)
p = "your are lucky" if your_fortune == 1 else "you are not lucky"
print p

raw_input("press enter to exit")
```